# AngularJS with PHP: why my app can't save strings sent by input text?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, angularjs

I've got an AngularJS with PHP app that save and search in a `mysql` database.

In my index.html, I have a table that shows all records in the database, a form with two input text and a button that saves the informations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="carApp" ng-controller="carCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <p>Simple CRUD in AngularJS and PHP</p>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Plate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in cars">
                <td>{{c.car_id}}</td>
                <td>{{c.car_name}}</td>
                <td>{{c.car_plate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br /> <br />

        <h3>New Car</h3>
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Car Name: {{name}}</label> <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Car Plate: {{plate}}</label> <input type="text" ng-model="plate" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('carApp', []);
        app.controller('carCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.cars = [];
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.plate = '';

            getCars();

            $scope.save = function() {
                var car = {
                    name : $scope.name,
                    plate : $scope.plate
                };

                $http.post("../database/insert/newCar.php", car).success(
                        function() {
                            console.log(car);
                            getCars();
                        });
            };

            function getCars() {
                $http.get("../database/select/cars.php").success(
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.cars = response;
                        });
            }
            ;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The search in database is OK, but when I try to make an insert, the app only saves if both fields are filled with `numbers`. When I try to save `strings`, nothing is saved. I don't know why this is happening, because i'm using input type `text` in both fields and the columns in database are `varchar`.

> EG:
>  Car Name: 111111111, Car Plate: 1111111111 
>  Result:
>   Information Saved.
>  Car Name: 333333333, Car Plate:
>   12345667
>  Result: Information Saved
>  Car Name:
>   333333333, Car Plate: 12 34 56 67
>  Result: Information not
>   Saved
>  Car Name: 333 33 33 33, Car Plate: 12345667
>   Result: Information not Saved
>  Car Name: aaaaaaaaaa, Car
>   Plate: bbbbbbbbb
>  Result: Information not Saved
>  Car
>   Name: hj3k4hjk34h, Car Plate: 1a2b3ce49
>  Result: Information not
>   Saved

here is newCar.php:

```
<?php
    include '../connector/mysql_connection.inc';

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $car = json_decode($json);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `testing_angular`.`car` (`car_name`, `car_plate`) VALUES (" . $car->name . ", " . $car->plate . ");"; 

    $connection->query($sql);
    $connection->close();
?>
```

here is the table 'car':

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car`(
    `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `car_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `car_plate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `car_plate` (`car_plate`)
);
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting $car before the insert? That would help you narrow it down at least.

Comment: i tried  echo $car->name;  but i got no answer...

Comment: @herbert Have you tried doing this using a service asynchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would work better if you quoted your insert values like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `testing_angular`.`car` (`car_name`, `car_plate`) 
    VALUES ('" . $car->name . "', '" . $car->plate . "');";
```

Of course then there are the usual problems with SQL injection when constructing statements this way.

Comment: thanks, man! I thought that the problem was in another place, but not in SQL.

Comment: Read about PDO and prepared statements.  Life will be so much easier and secure.

Comment: No problem. The fact that it worked sometimes made me suspect SQL first. In my experience with this, if the problem is with the PHP or Javascript it is more likely to work never. And yes, prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this
`$http.post("../database/insert/newCar.php", car).success(
                        function() {
                            console.log(car);
                            getCars();
                        });`

`$http.post("../database/insert/newCar.php", car).success(
                        function(respone) {
                             $scope.cars = response;
                        });`

In the php file after save send searched data to front. It is more efficent way to do that.

Try to make it this way
`$car = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$sql = 
"INSERT INTO`testing_angular`.`car`(`car_name`,`car_plate`) 
    VALUES ('" . $car['name'] . "', '" . $car['plate'] . "');";`

try to var_dump $car after decode.

write sql by hand with data to save
chceck data after decode function